# How do I fix this line of code so that I don't get any syntax errors?

Tags: python, syntax

I'm very new, so please go easy on me.

I keep getting syntax error codes for this section (specifically the "print()" and have no clue what I'm doing wrong? Could anyone give it a look over and let me know?

```
def name():  
    NAME=str(input("Why don't you introduce yourself to them, now that you've caught their eyes?")
    print(,NAME, "? Is that right? -yes/no-")
    answer = input(">").lower()
```

Comment: How about removing the first comma (`,`) from your `print` line? Also your second line needs one more `)` at the end.

Comment: Two things, remoe the `,` from line 3 and add an extra `)` to the end of `NAME`

Answer (score 0):

Here's the fixed code:

```
def name():  
    NAME = input("Why don't you introduce yourself to them, now that you've caught their eyes?")
    print(NAME, "? Is that right? -yes/no-")
    answer = input(">").lower()
```

Answer (score 0):

You have two syntax errors in your code.

The first one is that you are missing `)` at the end of line 2. Line 2 should look like this

`NAME=str(input("Why don't you introduce yourself to them, now that you've caught their eyes?"))`

Your second syntax error is you have a preceding `,` comma infront of your first variable.
Remove that comma, so that your 3rd line looks like this

`print(NAME, "? Is that right? -yes/no-")`

Answer (score 0):

**you miss ')' for str function and next line you  have extra ','  in print function**